# Wrap rows that have duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I've got data that looks like this:

```
BOB  | 4
BOB  | 3
BOB  | 7
MARY | 1
JOE  | 2
JOE  | 1
MIKE | 6
```

I want to end up with data that looks like this:

```
BOB  | 4 | 3 | 7
MARY | 1 |   |
JOE  | 2 | 1 |
MIKE | 6 |   |
```

The problem is, how do I account for the variable number of times a name shows up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the following code. It feels like it could be cleaner.

This will work for any selected block of data on your sheet (assuming it is pre-sorted). It outputs on the same sheet in the same area.

```
Sub WrapDuplicates()
    Dim data(), i As Long, startCell As Range, rwCnt As Long, col As Long

    data = Selection //pull selected data into an array
    Set startCell = Selection.Cells(1, 1) //Get reference to write results to
    Selection.ClearContents //remove original data
    startCell = data(1, 1) //Output first name
    startCell.Offset(0, 1) = data(1, 2) //Output first value

    rwCnt = 0
    col = 2

    For i = 2 To UBound(data) //Loop through array and check if name is same or not and output accordingly
        If data(i, 1) = data(i - 1, 1) Then
            startCell.Offset(rwCnt, col) = data(i, 2)
            col = col + 1
        Else
            rwCnt = rwCnt + 1
            col = 2
            startCell.Offset(rwCnt, 0) = data(i, 1)
            startCell.Offset(rwCnt, 1) = data(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked as expected but I got an error on this piece of code: "startCell.Offset(rwCnt, col) = data(i, 2)"

Error message: "1004 - Application-defined or Object-defined error"

Comment: When you say it 'worked as expected' did you get the right output or are you saying the code failed with the error you mention?

Comment: It wrapped the text just like I wanted, but finished up with that error message.

Comment: I didn't get that error message but I was using Excel 2003. You can always add `On error resume next` at the top of the code to swallow the error **assuming** you are satisfied you are getting the right output...

Comment: Yes, that may be the difference... I'm using 2010. I added that line to the top of the code and it all works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: I almost hate to ask, but is there a way to modify the code for 3 columns (instead of 2)????

Comment: What do you mean? Two columns of names and one of value?

Comment: One column that is name and 2 columns that are values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to do this in code based on the excel-vba tag in your post.

I'm also assuming the data is sorted by name, or you are OK with sorting it by name before the code executes.

Source is in sheet 1, target is in sheet 2.  Code is in Excel VBA.  I tested with your sample data, dropping this subroutine in the ThisWorkbook section of the Excel codebehind and pressing play.

The target header gets rewritten every time, which isn't ideal from a performance perspective, but I don't think is a problem otherwise.  You could wrap it in an if statement that checks the target column index = 2 if it becomes a problem.

```
Sub ColumnsToRows()

Dim rowHeading
Dim previousRowHeading
Dim sourceRowIndex
Dim targetRowIndex
Dim targetColumnIndex


sourceRowIndex = 1
targetRowIndex = 1
targetColumnIndex = 2

rowHeading = Sheet1.Cells(sourceRowIndex, 1)
previousRowHeading = rowHeading

While Not rowHeading = ""

    If Not previousRowHeading = rowHeading Then
        targetRowIndex = targetRowIndex + 1
        targetColumnIndex = 2
    End If

    Sheet2.Cells(targetRowIndex, 1) = rowHeading
    Sheet2.Cells(targetRowIndex, targetColumnIndex) = Sheet1.Cells(sourceRowIndex, 2)
    previousRowHeading = rowHeading

    sourceRowIndex = sourceRowIndex + 1
    targetColumnIndex = targetColumnIndex + 1
    rowHeading = Sheet1.Cells(sourceRowIndex, 1)

Wend

End Sub
```

I'm a developer, not an Excel guru.  There may be some Excel function, pivot table, or some other Excel magic that does this for you automatically.

Comment: GOOD NEWS: The code looks great and, Yes, VBA is fine. Data is already sorted.

Comment: BAD NEWS: The code doesn't seem to do anything. I run it and it doesn't give me any kind of message or errors -- it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you look at sheet 2? The data should be there. It was when I ran it.

Comment: One caveat, the code thinks the game is over when it sees a blank value in column 1. So your data needs to start on the very first cell of the page, and not have any blank lines.

Comment: Yes, my test data starts in A1

Comment: When I did my test, I started with a new worksheet.  That worksheet had a sheet2 already.  Would you try pasting your data into a new, blank sheet with multiple fresh pages?

Comment: Started with empty Excel file (Sheets 1 thru 3). Imported your code into the ThisWorkbook code. Executed the code. Still nothing happened. No error message or anything. Sheet2 still empty.